# Secure spring boot app without user log on

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, websecurity

I am creating a spring boot API and react front end in a project I am working on. There is no user logon on the front end, however, I would like to ensure my API endpoints are secure and only accessed by my react front end and I am struggling to come up with solutions.

One possible solution I was thinking is to secure the API with JWT. Create a user table and create a user for the front end client. When the user visits the front end get a token and validate this token on all requests. I’m not sure if this is a valid approach or if there is another solution better fitted.

The app will be hosted on Heroku, stack: spring boot, react and MySQL database. Anyone come across this before or any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: hi, interesting, you could use `HttpRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid()` or `HttpRequest.getSession(false) != null`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Since you don't require a login the data/actions by provided by the api are accessible by the public anyway?

Comment: I am creating an e-commerce site, where the user can checkout as a guest, where I will be working with product ID's on the client which i guessed would need to be secure and only known to verified clients. I am using Stripe for payments so no card information will be passed between API and client.

Comment: What damage can a malicious user do with the product ids?

Comment: Very good question, they wont be able to do anything with it as there are no endpoints for this. The more I think about it I feel I may be over complicating this. So it would be OK to have public API endpoints that don't expose any sensitive data?

Comment: If you, others in your organisation, or the law, can not think of a reason for it to be secret, I would say it's safe for it to be public.

Comment: If the data is useful, and you have many consumers, you might incur costs though because you'll need a better server to serve more traffic. So that could be a reason why you would want to limit access. This you could achieve with some form of rate limiting though.

Comment: There is an approach called "threat modelling" which deals with identifying relevant threats and appropriately securing against them. This might be of interest to you.

Comment: Yes I plan to use rate limiting and I will check out the threat modelling model. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.

At its core, this would require the frontend to have access to some secret value with which to authenticate it's request with, i.e. a token. You would then allow requests based on the presence of this secret value, and serve the responses.

However, frontends serve public assets and thus can't have secrets. At the end of the day, any user would be able to inspect their network requests, and extract the token from the requests your frontend makes.

With this information they can then forge their own requests.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add domain at allowedOrigins of CORS config :

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class CorsFilterConfig {

    public static final List<String> allowedOrigins = Arrays.asList("yourDomainsHere");

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> initCorsFilter() {
        // @formatter:off
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        config.setAllowedOrigins(allowedOrigins);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

[More](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)

Comment: CORS protects users in the frontend, it does not protect the backend.

Comment: If I want to access the api outside of the browser, CORS will not prevent that.

Comment: You can also run your browser without CORS, completely side stepping this mechanism.

Comment: No other way then